# What shell/env variable contains commandline suggestions?

Tags: bash, debian, shell, centos, environment-variables

Many years ago someone once showed me that if your shell returned a command suggestion then you could access it from a shell or environment variable. I thought this was very cool at the time but I wasn't using Linux that regularly so forgot how to do it.

I can't ask that person any more and for years it has bugged me how to do it and from time to time I Google it loads but can never find it. Maybe I am using the wrong language or maybe I've remembered some detail wrong that is throwing Google off but I always just get beginner guides to shell/env variables and they don't contain what I'm looking for.

**Example: **
Given the following scenario:

```
$ apt-show-versions vim

Command 'apt-show-versions' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install apt-show-versions
```

then there exists some variable (let's call it `SOME_VARIABLE`) such that you can enter the command `sudo apt install apt-show-versions` just by typing `$SOME_VARIABLE`.

Please do not take the above example too literally. I cannot remember *any* details about *how* it was implemented. All I remember is that if the command line suggested that I run a command, then I could run that command very easily by typing something short and not having to copy and paste the suggestion manually. Maybe it uses `eval $SOME_VARIABLE` maybe it doesn't use a variable at all or maybe this is correct but `apt` doesn't allow you to run their `suggestions` and I need to pick another example.

I've looked through `env` and `printenv` but couldn't find anything suitable.

I currently use Debian-based distros but I might have been using CentOS at the time and so maybe the problem is that it's something specific to CentOS.

If anyone knows anything about this then I would love to hear it since it has bugged me for years about why I couldn't find it!

Comment: Are you _sure_ you have the context right? You are saying there is a special trick that somehow parses the multi-line output of a command to somehow extract only the part you want to run? Could you be instead thinking of a variable that holds the argument given to the last command?

Comment: If that "command not found" handler runs inside the shell, it could indeed set a shell variable. But I don't know if they're implemented like that, or if it's just arranged that the shell calls an external program.

Comment: `env` would only show exported variables (IIRC), you could try checking the output of `set`

Comment: @terdon I don't know how it works. At the time I imagined that maybe if you write the src of the command in the right way then maybe it would automatically add it to some variable and that just became a common thing to do for popular tools but that is wild speculation on my part.

I'm not sure what you mean? Can you elaborate on what you are thinking of? Are you referring to `$_`? I don't think it is that.

Comment: @ilkkachu do you know how I might find out if that is the case?

Thanks for the reminder about `set`! I will check it out but it looks like there's a lot there so will need to come back to that when I have a bit more time.

Comment: @ilkkachu I have just realised that there is `command_not_foudn` in `set`. Will dig into this more ASAP although I'm not really sure where the best place to start is.

Comment: Are you perhaps just remembering that *setting* an environment variable causes this message to include a prompt to install the package in question? If you set  the `COMMAND_NOT_FOUND_INSTALL_PROMPT` variable to anything, the Ubuntu `command-not-found` helper will do so.